# Easier attendance method to Skype for Business meetings?

Tags: lync, skype-for-business-2016

Our organisation uses the native desktop Skype for Business 2016 client.

When I want to have meetings with external users I send them the standard Outlook invitation created by the S4B add-in.

This works fine for most users, but for some external clients they are restricted by security policies and are unable to download the MSI plug-in required for web meetings.

Is there a way round this?  Is it possible to host a Skype meeting and invite external users with the minimum fuss?

I came across [this page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Join-a-Skype-for-Business-meeting-with-Skype-Meetings-App-Skype-for-Business-Web-App-4828ad18-ed21-422a-a870-94d676d4b72a) which may be relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a so called "web client" (called web app in Skype for Business) which must be downloaded and used and in a restricted environment the user isn´t able to perform that. However the local IT can rollout the web client to those users (see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praj/2016/04/23/simplifying-skype-for-business-web-app-plugin-installation-on-clients-to-join-skype-for-business-2015-meetings/)). The best way would be if the user test the connection before the real meeting and then get in contact with the local IT to prepare the machine (e.g. install the plugin).

Unfortunately there is no other option.

Comment: That's a real shame.  We moved away from GoToMeeting to S4B and this is becoming a problem.  GoToMeeting does not require any downloads to work in a browser

Comment: yes but you could vote [here](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/11531631-attend-skype-session-without-administrative-rights) and leave a comment that this should be implemented. You should also get in contact with your Microsoft TAM so he could raise a feature request. If a lot of persons will do that, Microsoft can discover then that this is a very highly requested feature.